# Vertica Correlate Subquery with NOT IN clause

Tags: vertica

I have put all the DDL and query in sqlfiddel  link below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89c76/2

Same thing here

```
create table players(name varchar(32),playerid int);
insert into players values("a",1);
insert into players values("b",2);
insert into players values("c",3);
insert into players values("d",4);
insert into players values("e",5);
insert into players values("f",6);

select * from players;

create table matches(playerid int,game varchar(32));
insert into matches values(1,"game1");
insert into matches values(2,"game1");
insert into matches values(3,"game1");
insert into matches values(1,"game2");
insert into matches values(2,"game2");
insert into matches values(3,"game2");
insert into matches values(4,"game3");
insert into matches values(5,"game2");

select * from matches;

commit;
```

and the query is

```
select p.playerid,m.game
    from players p, (select distinct game from matches) m
    where p.playerid not in (select playerid from matches where game=m.game)
```

I get the following error

```
[Vertica][VJDBC](2795) ERROR: Correlated subquery with NOT IN is not supported [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=2795]
```

samething is mentioned in vertica doc.

How can I, rewrite this query?

I need results as

```
Result:
    ------------------------
    game1 | 4,5,6  
    ------------------------
    game2 | 4,6
    ------------------------
    game3 | 1,2,3,5,6
    ------------------------
    ....
```

**I had posted this issue in the vertica forum and found the solution through Kim_nicely 
https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/comment/240673#Comment_240673**

```
select p.playerid, m.game from players p cross join (select distinct game from matches) m
minus
select * from matches
order by 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query, the logic is to get all players that did not play in game1 and players that did not play any game. You can also get the players not in game1 by doing below. Notice the difference on the left join on m.game='game1'.
I can only do one game becuase the new requirements need stored procedure in vertica. I don't have experience on it but sql.

```
    select 'game1', group_concat(t.playerid) playerid
    from ( 
    select  p.playerid 
    from players p 
    left join matches m 
    on p.playerid = m.playerid and m.game='game1'
    where m.playerid is null
    UNION
    select p.playerid 
    from players p 
    left join matches m 
    on p.playerid = m.playerid 
    where m.playerid is null) t
```

Comment: Im usinf mobile phone so it is not pretty formatted. Will fix it once i log in my laptop. Thanks.

Comment: I formatted the code Thanks, Yes you got the problem correct. In addition, I want to fetch this result for all the games in matches table

Comment: the subquery the original problem is mainly used to solve this problem

Comment: Raj, I look around for vertica stored procedure and there is none that can answer your new requirements. I can only do one game1 but not all of them.

Comment: anonyXmous, I have updtade the question with solution

Comment: THanks Raj; my version of mySQL does not have 'minus'. Good job for finding your answer.